# Sorting checking after swaps

Tags: algorithm, sorting, c++11

So I've got a problem with one task.

You have given sequence of numbers and n operations in each there are two numbers (indexes in this given sequence).

You have to check if sequence after each operation will be sorted or not. (Every operation is applied).

My problem is that my solution is too slow. It works in O(n^2). (I'm just making swap and using is_sorted from c++11). How to make it faster ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not clear on the nature of the operations.  Are you saying each operation is affecting only the two numbers whose indexes are given in that operation?  Could you give an example? (i.e. show a sample sequence, the specs for one operation, and the resulting sequence)

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us what you have already tried.

Comment: This question is not actual because I wrote correctly working code last Friday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are saying is that you have a sequence, say...

```
3, 9, 34, 8, 5, 25, 10
```

and an operation that swaps two of the numbers, so swap[2, 4] (zero indexed of course) would yield

```
3, 9, 5, 8, 34, 25, 10
```

Even if the operation does not swap, but rather performs some other operation that acts on only those two numbers, this algorithm would work; in fact, this will work for anything that changes any number in that array:

First, I would keep a helper array of booleans that tells me whether each member of my sequence is greater than the number before it, indicating that this number is in place or in sequence in relation to the one before it.  Then, I would also keep a count of how many of these booleans are true.  The sequence is sorted when the count of numbers that are in place is equal to the number of items in the sequence.  When a change is made to any number in the sequence, I check with the following algorithm:

```
float MySequence[LengthOfSequence];
bool IsNumInPlace[LengthOfSequence];
int CountOfNumsInPlace;

... something loads MySequence ...

// this starts that helper array of booleans
IsNumInPlace[0] = true;
CountOfNumsInPlace = 1;
for (i = 1; i < LengthOfSequence; i++) {
   IsNumInPlace[i] = (MySequence[i] > MySequence[i-1]);
   if (IsNumInPlace[i]) CountOfNumsInPlace++;
}


... something changes item at index "x" in the sequence ...
// whether this number, and possibly the one after it, are in place, needs
// to be rechecked
CheckThisItem(x);
if (x < LengthOfSequence - 1) CheckThisItem(x + 1);

... the array is sorted, at this point, if CountOfNumsInPlace is equal to the number of items in the array ...
```

The key is in this little function that increases or decreases the count of "items in place", depending on whether the value at the given index is greater than or equal to the value of the item before it.

```
private void CheckThisItem(int ItemChanged) {
    bool IsNewNumInPlace= (ItemChanged == 0) ||
                          (MySequence[ItemChanged] >= MySequence[ItemChanged - 1]);
    if (IsNumInPlace[ItemChanged] && !IsNewNumInPlace) {
        CountOfNumsInPlace--;
    } else if (!IsNumInPlace[ItemChanged] && IsNewNumInPlace) {
        CountOfNumsInPlace++;
    }
    IsNumInPlace[ItemChanged] = IsNewNumInPlace;
}
```

This should give you an algorithm that works in O(n).  You are not recomparing every item in the array against those around it to see if the array is in sequence, even the ones that were not affected.  You are **only** comparing the item changed against the one before it and the one after it.

Notice that the first item in the array is considered to be "in place" in relation to the item before it.  Since there is no item before it (it is the first one), there is nothing to say it is out of place, so it is "ok" as far as sorting goes.

If your operation makes a change to two of the items in the sequence, then just do that last part twice, once for each number changed.

Comment: you also have to compare the changed item against the one after it -- [1,0,3] -> [1,5,3] changes *two* Booleans.

Comment: @MattTimmermans - yes, I had caught that and was working on editing the answer when I saw your comment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [great cheat sheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) for several kinds of sorting algorithms; a
[Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) seems like it would do the trick for you (it's O(n+k)):

1. determine an integer 'key' for each object in your list
2. run the counting sort
3. it runs once, then everything is sorted, so you know 
   when everything is sorted.

Here's the pseudocode from Wikipedia, just in case the links break.

```
# variables:
#    input -- the array of items to be sorted; 
#    key(x) -- function that returns the key for item x
#    k -- a number such that all keys are in the range 0..k-1
#    count -- an array of numbers, with indexes 0..k-1, initially all zero
#    output -- an array of items, with indexes 0..n-1
#    x -- an individual input item, used within the algorithm
#    total, oldCount, i -- numbers used within the algorithm
#    Big O:  O(n + k)

# calculate the histogram of key frequencies:
for x in input:
    count[key(x)] += 1

# calculate the starting index for each key:
total = 0
for i in range(k):   # i = 0, 1, ... k-1
    oldCount = count[i]
    count[i] = total
    total += oldCount

# copy to output array, preserving order of inputs with equal keys:
for x in input:
    output[count[key(x)]] = x
    count[key(x)] += 1

return output
```

Comment: Counting sort only works in very constrained cases, and there is nothing in OP's question to indicate those constraints apply.  His numbers would have to be integers (which we do not know), and the variation (range) in the numbers would have to be comparable to the number of items in the sequence (this also, we do not know, and it is unlikely as it is only the rare dataset that does that).

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the sum of the absolute values of the differences between adjacent elements. When this sum is minimized, which will happen when it equals the max value minus the min value, then the list is sorted.

This requires one pass to compute the min and max values, and also to sum up the absolute values of the differences.

Every time you swap two elements, subtract from the sum the absolute values of the differences of each of the them from their neighbors before the swap, and then add them afterwards at their swapped positions. Then compare the new sum with max - min, when it's equal then stop. This is O(n) time and O(1) space.

Comment: +1. Very neat. To clarify, the initial pass to compute the max/min and the current deviation takes `O(n)`, but after that, it takes `O(1)` time to check whether the sequence is sorted or not after each operation, which is where the speed up is coming from.